# Can't find files in my Libary/Ethereum folder

Tags: javascript, file, terminal, ethereum

I have been working with this video. Its a really good series that shows you have to make your own cryptocurrency. I have run into many problems and was able to solve them but now I have run into another and I'm stuck. The problem is that with that video on minute 47:56 he has files that I don't. I have followed every single step but don't seem to have the files.

I have tried to find the library folder and then go to the ethereum folder but again can't find any files

I expect the output when I write `ls -l ~/Libary/Ethereum` it is meant to give me the files: `.DS_Store  geth/  history   keystore/   rinkeby/` but does not give them. To look at the video would be really useful because then you could see for yourself what I'm meant to get as an output but instead, I just get `total 0 srw-------  1 cinojaeger  staff  0 Dec 23 09:53 geth.ipc`

Thanks for your help :)

Link to video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTCAjtluS-A&index=15&list=PLS5SEs8ZftgWFuKg2wbm_0GLV0Tiy1R-n

remember minute 47:56 is where the problem occurs

Comment: Geth chaindata location is different per OS. See: [How can I find my `chaindata` folder?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6550/how-can-i-find-my-chaindata-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a possibility that you are spelling library wrong after your ls command?